# Leading dots before page numbers in ConTeXt registers

Tags: context

I would like to add leading dots before page numbers in ConTeXt registers. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Here is a minimal working example of the current behavior, and the behavior I would like it to produce:

```
\defineregister[cases][n=1,pagestyle=normal,indicator=no]

\setupcombinedlist[content][alternative=c]
\setuplist[chapter][headnumber=no]
\setuphead[chapter][number=no]

\starttext

\title{Table of Contents}

\placecontent

\chapter{Register Table}

\placecases

\chapter{Content}
This is a \cases{test}test. This is \cases{another test}another test.

\stoptext
```

The table of contents, using `alternative=c`, contains the leading dots:
[image: Leading Dots]

I would like the `cases` register to appear similarly. As it stands, it appears as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find anything to set the list alternative as for combined lists, but you can hijack the `textcommand` to insert the dots.  The distance between text and dots and number and dots can be tuned with the `distance` key.

```
\starttexdefinition unexpanded register:text #1
  #1
  \hskip\registerparameter{distance}\relax
  \dotfill
\stoptexdefinition

\defineregister
  [cases]
  [
    n=1,
    pagestyle=normal,
    indicator=no,
    distance=1em,
    textcommand=\getvalue{register:text},
  ]

\setupcombinedlist[content][alternative=c]
\setuplist[chapter][headnumber=no]
\setuphead[chapter][number=no]

\starttext

\title{Table of Contents}

\placecontent

\chapter{Register Table}

\placecases

\chapter{Content}
This is a \cases{test}test. This is \cases{another test}another test. \dorecurse{5}{\input knuth} This is a \cases{test}test. This is \cases{another test}another test.

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

If you want to have *exactly* the same dots as in the list alternative `c` for the combined list, use the following `textcommand` in conjunction with `distance=.5em`.

```
\starttexdefinition unexpanded register:text #1
  #1
  \hskip\registerparameter{distance}\relax
  \gleaders\hbox to .5em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
\stoptexdefinition
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the proposed solution adds dots between multiple page numbers as well. For example, if an index entry for ```test``` appears on both page 1 and page 2, the table appears "test .... 1, .... 2". 

You can generate this effect by using the following code for the body text: ```This is a \cases{test}test. This is \cases{another test}another test.

\dorecurse{5}{\input knuth}

This is a \cases{test}test. This is \cases{another test}another test.```

Comment: @J.King You are right.  Better hijack `textcommand`.  See updated answer.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you! Hijacking ```textcommand``` rather than ```pagecommand``` makes a lot of sense, and it produces the desired result.

Interestingly, the ```\dotfill``` solution doesn't work for me in my full document, but I'm not going to worry about it for now because the ```\gleaders``` version works. Thanks again!